# OpenVPN on an AWS instance breaks connectivity

Tags: ubuntu, networking, amazon-ec2, openvpn

**Summary**: I want to set up an OpenVPN server on an EC2 instance ([Ubuntu 16.04](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/locator/ec2/)). It fails to configure its interfaces after a reboot.

**Details**:

- the image installs fine, reboots fine
- `apt update ; apt get openvpn` brings in OpenVPN correctly
- a minimal test setup with a [shared key](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/miscellaneous/78-static-key-mini-howto.html) works when started from the command line (`udp/1945` is listening)

At this stage everything is OK.

When rebooting this machine fails its status checks

[image]

The server logs show that the machine fails to raise its network interfaces:

```
(...)

[    6.624548] cloud-init[519]: Cloud-init v. 0.7.7 running 'init-local' at Mon, 06 Jun 2016 13:36:41 +0000. Up 6.36 seconds.
OK Started Initial cloud-init job (pre-networking).
OK Reached target Network (Pre).
         Starting Raise network interfaces...
OK Started ifup for tun0.
OK Found device /sys/subsystem/net/devices/tun0.
* A start job is running for Raise network interfaces (7s / 5min 1s)

(...)

* A start job is running for Raise network interfaces (30s / 5min 1s)
* A start job is running for Raise network interfaces (30s / 5min 30s)
FAILED Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
See 'systemctl status networking.service' for details.
DEPEND Dependency failed for Initial cloud... job (metadata service crawler).
OK Reached target Network.
         Starting OpenVPN service...
         Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
(...)

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS ip-172-31-16-245 ttyS0

ip-172-31-16-245 login:
```

**What is specific in the way an EC2 instance configures its interfaces?**

The same setup on a hardware server works without problems, so I assume that this must be something specific to EC2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The systemd service file for OpenVPN (`/lib/systemd/system/openvpn@.service`) must be updated with a `After=network.target network-online.target` entry:

```
[Unit]
Description=OpenVPN connection to %i
PartOf=openvpn.service
ReloadPropagatedFrom=openvpn.service
Before=systemd-user-sessions.service
After=network.target network-online.target # This is needed
Documentation=man:openvpn(8)
Documentation=https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn23ManPage
Documentation=https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/HOWTO
```

All credit goes to [sc250024](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=719587) who posted a [solution](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=719587) at the AWS forum.

EDIT: a [bug is filed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openvpn/+bug/1580356) with Canonical. No progress so far.